# TeamCity MSbuild Deploy procedure

Tags: asp.net, .net, msbuild, teamcity, webdeploy

I'm using TeamCity for deployment process. For deploy i'm running MSbuild with this command line parameters:

```
/P:Configuration=Release
/P:DeployOnBuild=True
/P:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish
/P:MsDeployServiceUrl=serviceUrl
/P:DeployIisAppPath=website
/P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
/P:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc
/P:username=username
/P:Password=password
/P:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True
/P:VisualStudioVersion=10.0
```

I have this parameter `P:SkipExtraFilesOnServer` set to true beacause i don't want MSbuild to delete some files which i have only on service enviroment, but don't have on my local project. But the problem is when i actually want to remove something from project (i have web application), i usually delete file from project, then i rebuild my app, and commit the changes in project file to source control, MSbuild leave this file on service because of this parameter. 
MSbuild is using Release configuration, which i specified to use "all files in this project" to deploy. So the behaviour i want to implement:

1. TeamCity will leave all files which are not in my project reference list. (`.csproj` file).
2. TeamCity will delete files which were in `.csproj` but was deleted from it.

Please help me with that task.

Comment: This behavior has nothing to do with TeamCity, it's just MSBuild, and it unlikely can be changed.

Comment: The files were removed from the project, but have they been deleted from source control?

Comment: yes, files were deleted from csproj file and source control